# how to bind multiple parameters to MySQLi query

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a mysql query, but I can't bind param for it

```
SELECT users.email,users.handle,userprofile.mobile FROM users,userprofile WHERE users.email =? OR users.handle =? OR userprofile.mobile=?
```

I've tried below line

```
$query = "SELECT users.email,users.handle,userprofile.mobile FROM users,userprofile WHERE users.email =? OR users.handle =? OR userprofile.mobile=?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("sss",$email,$username,$mobile);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
if($stmt->num_rows){
   echo '......';
    }
}
```

but I've received and error :

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type
>   definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

Comment: Can you post your entire query code including the full prepare not just the sql statement

Comment: Actually just relased your using bindParam its actually $stmt->bind_param() when you're passing multiple parameters in like your example

Comment: "sss" means that the 3 variables he wants to bind are all strings and he's passing all 3 variables in at once so he needs to use bind_param not bindparam.  He should only be using it without the _ if he's going to bind each input individually as in the example below.

Comment: I've edited my post to explain more code

Comment: You are actually opening mysqli in an OO method aren't you ie: `$mysqli = new mysqli(); ` not doing it in a procedural style are you in which case you'd have to pass in the link id too

Comment: @Dave, that would be a different error.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary thought it would be but also thought it was worth checking since I can't see anything else wrong with it unless its a case of can't see the wood for all the trees.

Comment: I'm wondering if you need a space before the `?`... Can't find the requirement in the docs, but try it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is the correct syntax for binding params in `mysqli`

```
$SQL = "SELECT 
              users.email,
              users.handle,
              userprofile.mobile 
        FROM users,userprofile      
        WHERE users.email =? OR users.handle =? OR userprofile.mobile=?";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($SQL);
   
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $one,$two,$three);
$stmt->execute();

//do stuff
```

Comment: can I call bind_params 3 times for binding different argument if I received them as an array?

Comment: Just to remind:
The argument may be one of four types:

i - integer
d - double
s - string
b - BLOB

Comment: What is diffrent between this solution and the code provided ?

Comment: @KoenDemonie Actually there is no difference but if you look at question history by clicking on "edited May 17 '13 at 15:11" you will spot the difference. Op was using bindParam instead of bind_param

Answer (score 5):

Try this...

```
$stmt = $dbConn->prepare("SELECT users.email,users.handle,userprofile.mobile FROM users,userprofile WHERE users.email = ? OR users.handle = ? OR userprofile.mobile= ?");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $email, $handle, $mobile);
$stmt->execute();
```