# how to show the total sum of amount between the entered date(start date --- end date) selected by user

Tags: php, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCJUz.png) how i can calculate the total sum between particular date (eg: 2016/06/16 to 2016 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo7oy.png)/08/17). and which the date will be choose by the user from front end.
I have tried something like this.

```
    $sql = "select sum(amount_no) from tsurphus where subDate BETWEEN '2016-03-01' AND '2016-08-05'";
    $q = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($q);
    echo 'Current Total Amount. Rs: ' . $row[0];
```

But here the problem is that to calculate the total amount i need to change the date from code. please help.. thank in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Nor how the title relates to the content

Comment: If I understand this correctly, your total is coming in currency Rs. Since you have different currencies, you want them to show total in USD, total in INR etc?

Comment: what are you getting.. and what did you expected

Comment: check your date format i think there is the problem

Comment: Are you looking for [binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612251/how-to-bind-multiple-parameters-to-mysqli-query) (and mysqli)?

Comment: You can store date in `TIMESTAMP` format in database and retrieve in query in `date()` format here

Comment: What is the data type of subDate column ?

Comment: SELECT sum(id) FROM `tbl_users`
where date_created between '2016-04-15 10:50:12' and '2016-04-17 10:50:12'   worked for me

Comment: @ObjectManipulator you got me correctly. please help.

Answer (score 1):

In your query, you should **group by the currency field.**

Considering your field name is "currency", try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(amount_no), currency FROM tsurphus WHERE subDate BETWEEN '2016-03-01' AND '2016-08-05' GROUP BY currency";
```